# Find coordinates for third point of a triangle given the other two points and their angles

Tags: trigonometry

I think this is best described by the picture below

[image]

Given coordinates for point A and B, and their angles (a and b), which formula can I use to get the coordinates for point C ?

Comment: Instead of thinking of _using_ a formula, think of using your head to _find_ a formula.  I.e. the formula is the last step, not the first.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I tried to find a formula, I asked my dad and my brother for help, both engineers, they said it was not possible. Maybe they misunderstood the question. I am not well versed into trigonometry, so I spent almost an entire night trying to figure out proportions and coming up with some equations. I gave up cause I know it would be smarter to ask for help from qualified persons, like yourself, sir. Thank you and Henning Makholm for the awesome quick reply.

Comment: If you told your father and your brother what you told us, then it would be irrational for them to say simply that it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The two blue lines have the equations
$$ k = -\tan(a)\cdot j $$
$$ k = -\tan(b)\cdot (x-j) $$
Solve this system of equations for $j$ and $k$.

Comment: this is indeed the nicest method, I guess.

Comment: Thank you @Henning Makholm, just thank you and have a nice day. =)

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556534/triangle-formula-for-alternative-points Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\text{slope} = \frac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}} = \frac k j = -\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = -\tan a.
$$
So the equation of the one of the lines is $y = -(\tan a)x$.

Similarly, the other one is $y=(\tan b) (x-x_0)$, where I take the coordinates of the point $B$ to be $(x_0,0)$.

So you need
$$
(\tan b) (x-x_0)=-(\tan a)x.
$$
$$
(\tan b+\tan a)x = (\tan b)x_0
$$
$$
x= \frac{(\tan b)x_0}{\tan b + \tan a}.
$$
$$
y = \frac{-(\tan a)(\tan b)x_0}{\tan b + \tan a}.
$$

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556534/triangle-formula-for-alternative-points Thanks!